# FLUTTER FACE_RECOGNITION AND POSE_ESTIMATION FOR WEB APPLICATION USING WEBCAM

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, flutter-web, google-mlkit, tflite

I have implemented the face recognition and pose estimation for android device. now I have to implement the same to web app. Can anyone please let me know, how to implement **face recognition** and **pose estimation** using **webcam** for web application. dependencies which I have using are  **google_ml_kit,tflite**. I know that **tflite** is only to **android/ios**. is there any specific dependencies for web to access.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that could be helpful to you:

(1) TFLite js https://www.google.com/search?q=tflite+js&oq=TFLite+js&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j0i22i30j69i65l3j69i60l3.2956j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

(2) MediaPipe JS API which supports both Face and Pose detection: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/javascript.html